# How to reserve a row for input in multi-threaded Console?

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

This question has bugged me for a while now, and I realize it's hard to describe what I am looking for. I want to be able to reserve a row for text input in a C# Console Application, while still allowing other information to be updated in the remaining rows. More specifically, I'd like to make a small mud game where the game is updated even while the user is busy making input. It's important that the input doesn't block the information flow.

I'd like to achieve the effect of the user writing input to the last visible row in the screen, while the other text append as usual, but not scrolling down my line of input, nor overwrite it.

If I would describe this in terms of Forms, I'd imagine the equivalent of having a multi-line textbox as the upper portion for the information, with a single-line textbox at the bottom for the input.

Answer (score 6):

One option that you could try, is to directly manipulate the console buffer to render your game area and use the Console.SetCursorPosition to position the cursor to the input line where you use Console.ReadLine for example to take the user input.

Since the direct manipulation of the buffer does not affect the cursor position and is independent of the Console Read/Write functionality you can have a thread updating the Console buffer which covers the first 24 lines and the 25 line is waiting for input. If I get some time I will try put together a sample of what I mean, but in the meantime you can reference the other answers I have provided for a pointer to writing directly to the Console buffer.

[How can I write fast colored output to Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754518/how-can-i-write-fast-colored-output-to-console/2754674#2754674)

[Deleting previously written lines in Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173750/deleting-previously-written-lines-in-console/3174089#3174089)

Of course you will want to write some nice wrapper functions to make this easy to work with, I always think about doing this, I just don't do enough work with the console so that I actually get down and do something.

**Update:** Added a small example of updating the console in a thread while still accepting user input. Just type 'quit' to stop it running. Note the the ConsoleBuffer class is not ideal, I am not closing the console handle, it was just a quick piece of code for the demo.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleDemo
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateConsole));
      t.IsBackground=true;
      t.Start();      

      string input;
      do
      {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 23);
        Console.Write("Command: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        ConsoleBuffer.ClearArea(0, 21, 80, 3);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 22);
        Console.Write(input);
      } while (!string.Equals(input, "quit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    static void UpdateConsole()
    {
      int i = 0;
      Random rnd = new Random();
      while (true)
      {
        string s = new string((char)(65 + (i % 26)),1);
        for (short x = 0; x < 80; ++x)
        {
          for (short y = 0; y < 20; ++y)
          {
            ConsoleBuffer.WriteAt(x, y, s);
            ConsoleBuffer.SetAttribute(x, y, (short)(rnd.Next(15)+1));
          }          
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  public class ConsoleBuffer
  {
    private static SafeFileHandle _hBuffer = null;

    static ConsoleBuffer()
    {
      _hBuffer = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

      if (_hBuffer.IsInvalid)
      {
        throw new Exception("Failed to open console buffer");
      }      
    }

    public static void WriteAt(short x, short y, string value)
    {
      int n = 0;
      WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(_hBuffer, value, value.Length, new Coord(x, y), ref n);
    }

    public static void SetAttribute(short x, short y, short attr)
    {
      SetAttribute( x, y, new short[] { attr });
    }

    public static void SetAttribute(short x, short y, short[] attrs)
    {
      int n = 0;
      WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(_hBuffer, attrs, attrs.Length, new Coord(x, y), ref n);
    }

    public static void ClearArea(short left, short top, short width, short height, char ch = ' ')
    {
      ClearArea(left, top, width, height, new CharInfo() { Char = new CharUnion() { UnicodeChar = ch } });
    }

    public static void ClearArea(short left, short top, short width, short height)
    {
      ClearArea(left, top, width, height, new CharInfo() { Char = new CharUnion() { AsciiChar = 32 } });
    }

    private static void ClearArea(short left, short top, short width, short height, CharInfo charAttr)
    {
      CharInfo[] buf = new CharInfo[width * height];
      for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; ++i)
      {
        buf[i] = charAttr;
      }

      SmallRect rect = new SmallRect() { Left = left, Top = top, Right = (short)(left + width), Bottom = (short)(top + height) };
      WriteConsoleOutput(_hBuffer, buf,
        new Coord() { X = width, Y = height },
        new Coord() { X = 0, Y = 0 },
        ref rect);      
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
      string fileName,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare,
      IntPtr securityAttributes,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags,
      IntPtr template);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteConsoleOutput(
      SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
      CharInfo[] lpBuffer,
      Coord dwBufferSize,
      Coord dwBufferCoord,
      ref SmallRect lpWriteRegion);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(
      SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
      string lpCharacter,
      int nLength,
      Coord dwWriteCoord,
      ref int lpumberOfCharsWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteConsoleOutputAttribute(
      SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
      short[] lpAttributes,
      int nLength,
      Coord dwWriteCoord,
      ref int lpumberOfAttrsWritten);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct Coord
    {
      public short X;
      public short Y;

      public Coord(short X, short Y)
      {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
      }
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct CharUnion
    {
      [FieldOffset(0)]
      public char UnicodeChar;
      [FieldOffset(0)]
      public byte AsciiChar;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct CharInfo
    {
      [FieldOffset(0)]
      public CharUnion Char;
      [FieldOffset(2)]
      public short Attributes;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct SmallRect
    {
      public short Left;
      public short Top;
      public short Right;
      public short Bottom;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dotNet Console supports `SetCursorPosition()` and you also use the old DOS trick of ending a line with `\r` instead of `\n\r`.

But multi-threading and Append doesn't sound like a good combination.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these .NET bindings for curses

http://www.mono-project.com/Libraries#Curses

ncurses is obviously a UNIX invention, but the API's are said to be mostly cross-platform (I haven't tried the .NET bindings myself, but have had very good results working with ncurses in general).

This will absolutely contain the goods you need and more