# Showing Timer on screen and asking for user input at the same time?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a c# console application.

I have to show a timer on screen at a specified cursor location and at the same time a user shall input something.

How can I do this?

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
//timer code here
Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y); // cursor goes to some other location because timer is displayed at top-right of the screen.
```

My problem is that this method isn't synchronized.
I have to wait until the cursor go to that location then display time and comes back so that I can type.

[image]

Comment: You say you are working on a console application, but you've tagged it with [tag:ASP.NET]. Explain?

Comment: `My problem is that this method isn't synchronized` what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you post some more code? For example where user input taken. Also posting the actual values of x and y will help too.

Comment: I'll try my best to explain.
I added a timer in my console application.
Here a pic how it looks.
http://i.imgur.com/Ckl9ADG.png

I'm using Console.SetCursorPosition to display the timer (Updates every second).
Then after that, i switch back to the area where the user is inputting the answer.

Are you getting it now?

Comment: I see what you mean. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772203/how-to-reserve-a-row-for-input-in-multi-threaded-console. From that link it doesn't seem like a straightforward task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) even while reading a line. See the code below for a working example:

```
class Program
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer( 1000 );
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Start();

        Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        Console.CursorTop = 5;
        // Type something here...
        var l_readline = Console.ReadLine();
        // Print it out... (to show it correctly reads the input)
        Console.WriteLine( l_readline );
        Console.ReadKey( true );
    }

    private static void Timer_Elapsed( object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {
        int l_left = Console.CursorLeft;
        int l_top = Console.CursorTop;

        Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        Console.CursorTop = 0;
        Console.Write( DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() );
        Console.CursorLeft = l_left;
        Console.CursorTop = l_top;
    }

}
```

As long as you reset the cursor position back to it's original position after you are finished, I do not think you will have much trouble with most forms of input.

Comment: That's a [Cyberman](https://www.google.com/search?q=cyberman&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=P6hVUvqNKu66yAHN1ICQDw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=775&dpr=1) from Dr. Who!

Comment: Thank you, kind sir.
Wish i could rep you but can't.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle something like this would be to store the current **Cursor(X, Y)**, write the time to your **Time(X, Y)**, then set the cursor back to **Cursor(X, Y)**.

```
private const int TIME_LEFT = 40;
private const int TIME_RIGHT = 2;

private void WriteTime() {
  var left = Console.CursorLeft;
  var right = Console.CursorTop;
  try {
    Console.SetCursorPosition(TIME_LEFT, TIME_RIGHT);
    Console.Write(DateTime.Now);
  } finally {
    Console.SetCursorPosition(left, right);
  }
}
```

Not knowing what else you are doing, that's the best suggestion I have for you.

This should occur faster than humans can react to.