# How to clear a specific block of statement in console aside from Console.Clear()?

Tags: c#, console-application

Can you please help me on how to clear a specific block of statements without clearing or removing the previous lines in console? If I use the `Console.Clear` method, the previous lines were cleared and only the line or statement after the `Console.Clear` method have appeared.

Is there method aside from `Console.Clear` that I can use to clear a specific block of statements without removing the previous lines?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you add your code ?

Comment: You need to do it by yourself actually. What I mean by that is; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173750/deleting-previously-written-lines-in-console or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console

Comment: Please review the documentation for [the Console class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx), where you will find details such as the `CursorLeft` and `CursorTop` properties, which you can use to position the cursor so that you can overwrite whatever text is present at that location. If and when you have some actual code and have tried to make the API work as you need it, but still have a _specific_ question, please of course feel free to ask that on-topic question.