# How to make a Console Full-Screen in C#

Tags: c#, console-application, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# full screen console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423085/c-sharp-full-screen-console)

I am trying to make one of my applications console full-screen, no borders, no task bar, etc.
How can use the entire screen ?
Thanks!

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/q/4423085/1004522 already on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in Windows 7 or Vista as they don't support it. On Windows XP you could use 
[the SetConsoleDisplayMode function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686028%28VS.85%29.aspx), you'd have to use PInvoke though and it will give you an error if ran under Windows 7 or Vista.

Comment: thanks!
but, you can give me a example for XP ?

Answer (score 0):

When the command prompt is open you can right click on the titlebar, select `properties` and change the width and height under `Layout`. I don't think you can make it application specific though.