# SetConsoleDisplayMode() function is not working setting my window to fullscreen

Tags: c++, windows

I have these global variables:

```
//width and height of the window
int WIDTH = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int HEIGHT = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
//width and height of one character, font dimensions
constexpr int dW = 8, dH = 8;
```

I'm trying to create an ASCII engine and this is the function to set up the window, it's only used once at the beginning of the program.

```
//set the font
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cf = {0};
    cf.cbSize = sizeof cf;
    cf.dwFontSize.X = dW;
    cf.dwFontSize.Y = dH;
    wcscpy(cf.FaceName, L"Terminal");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0, &cf);

    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    RECT ConsoleRect;
    GetWindowRect(console, &ConsoleRect);
    HANDLE hstdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hstdout, &csbi);

//set the window
//fullscreen and remove vertical bar
    csbi.dwSize.X = csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.X;
    csbi.dwSize.Y = csbi.dwMaximumWindowSize.Y;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hstdout, csbi.dwSize);
    MoveWindow(console, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, TRUE);
    SetConsoleDisplayMode(hstdout, CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, 0);
    ShowScrollBar(console, SB_BOTH, FALSE);
```

Before my code worked, but I changed something minor, and I changed something in window console settings and now it doesn't work.

I'm using Visual Studio if that's important.

Comment: When I run this code it sets the console to fullscreen. The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: This is one reason it's good to use a version control system even for small private projects. If you have a VCS then you can keep track of changes, and can roll back to previous (working) "versions". Unless you can remember the exact changes you've made, then it's hard to tell you what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not hardcore Windows programmer but SetConsoleDisplayMode()
is not supported everywhere, you can check if it's worked by calling GetLastError();

To open maximized console you can try my code below.

If you really want to get your code working call GetLastError after every windows function call maybe there is an error somewhere.

```
hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

auto check_error = [](bool state, const std::string& msg) {
    if (!state) {
        auto error = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << msg << ' ' << error << std::endl;
    }
};

short font_size = 4;
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi{ .cbSize = sizeof(cfi), .nFont = 0,
    .dwFontSize = {font_size, font_size}, 
    .FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE,
    .FontWeight = FW_NORMAL};

wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas");
bool state = SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, false, &cfi);
check_error(state, "Set Console font error");

COORD coord = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hConsole);
screenWidth = coord.X * font_size;
screenHeight = coord.Y * font_size;

HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
state = MoveWindow(console, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight,  TRUE);
check_error(state, "Move console error");
state = ShowScrollBar(console, SB_BOTH, FALSE);
check_error(state, "Show scroll bar error");
```