# Alternatives To The console.SetCursorPosition method

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, console-application

Hi i have to display various symbols at different places in the console window using x and y coordinates however i am not allowed to use the `Console.SetCursorPosition()` method. This is how it was done with the method

```
        string k="$";
        string l="%";

        Console.SetCursorPosition(30, 20);
        Console.Write(k);

        Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 6);
        Console.Write(l);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I need a way around using the `Console.SetCursorPosition()` method. Any alternatives will help i was told to use treat it like looping through a multi-dimensional array but i have made no headway. thanks alot for all the help in advanced

Comment: See if this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754518/how-can-i-write-fast-colored-output-to-console) Helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have any method replacing `SetCursorPosition` (also the `CursorLeft` and `CursorTop` properties). However I understand that you don't want the cursor to jump on the window when you `Write` something. Here is a work around for you:

```
public static void WriteAt(int left, int top, string s){
   int currentLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
   int currentTop = Console.CursorTop;
   Console.CursorVisible = false;//Hide cursor
   Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
   Console.Write(s);
   Console.SetCursorPosition(currentLeft, currentTop);
   Console.CursorVisible = true;//Show cursor back
}
//Use it
WriteAt(30, 20, k);
WriteAt(15, 6, l);
```

The point is we hide the cursor before changing its position and write all string, after finishing writing string, we move it back to the old position and show it back.

**NOTE**: Anyway, for your requirement which restricts you from using `SetCursorPosition` (looks like some kind of riddle/challenge :), you can always use `Console.CursorLeft` and `Console.CursorTop` instead to change the cursor position.

Comment: Thanks a lot it really helped. By the way Yes the question was a challenge from my programming professor